# $n$-th Derivative of $2^x$

Tags: calculus

Can anybody help me in solving the $n$th derivative of $2^x$?

Currently I have:

$\ln(2)!2^x$

however I'm not sure if it's right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have the right basic idea, but something went wrong when you decided that a bunch of $\ln2$s would multiply together to $(\ln 2)!$. That's not even meaningful; factorials are only for integers.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $2^x = e^{x\ln 2}$. Can you continue?

Comment: I still don't understand. I figured out that the derivative is 2^xln(2)

Comment: To find the derivative? I thought I already found it.

Comment: if $f(x) = e^{ax}$ where $a$ is a constant, then $f'(x) = a e^{ax}$ by the chain rule. Similarly, $f''(x) = a^2 e^{ax} $. In particular, $f^{n}(x) = a^n e^{ax} $. Now, in your problem you have $a = \ln 2 $

Comment: So based on your formula the answer would be: $\ln(2)^ne^(ln(2)x)$

Comment: yes, $$f^n(x) = (\ln 2)^n e^{\ln 2 x} $$

Comment: You the man Willie. How do you do multiple letters or numbers as an exponent? I couldn't get the formatting to work.

Comment: no problem bro. $a \times a \times ... \times a = a^n $

Comment: Ahh, I mean like in the text on StackOverflow. I can't get the ln2x to be an exponent of the e in my comment.

Comment: e^{ \ln 2 x} ...